# Como fazer listagem ordenada por letra?

Tags: javascript, array, for

Suponho que tenho uma lista com nomes, em *array* no Javascript. Porém busco uma forma de fazer ao estilo caixa de sugestões, onde você só pressiona uma tecla alfabética dentro do campo e tão logo lhe é exibida dicas de palavras chaves referente a letra digitada.

Segue um simples exemplo base de Listagem Ordenada em ordem alfabética:

```
<script>
    letras = new Array("C","B","A");
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{ 
    letras.sort();
    document.write(+ i + " array: " + letras[i]);
    document.write("<br>"); 
}           
</script>
```

No caso, desejo fazer algo dinâmico a partir desse simples exemplo acima que seria uma pagina com `campo` + `div` = `resultado(array)`

Basta você digitar uma letra e seria mostrado somente cujo nome inicia-se com a letra não importando a posição do `vetor` / `array` ignorando a exibição das demais dentro da `div`. Bom pessoal, a lógica é essa, se alguém puder me dar dicas e/ou simples exemplos será de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça algo assim:

```
letras.filter(function(item){
   var inputValue = document.getElementByid('id').value;
   var regex = new RegExp(inputValue);
   return item.match(regex);
});
```

Olha o exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/mgv2uyw1/
Isso é +- como deve ser feito, você pode elaborar mais as regularExpression para ficar de uma forma q vc prefira.

Comment: Creio que para ficar 100% teria de alterar a REGEX para `'/'+inputValue+'.*/i'`, se manter assim, só vai retornar item que sejam exatamente igual ao inputValue.

Comment: `RegExp('^'+inputValue+'.*', 'i'); `

Comment: Eu fiz testes e aparentemente qndo vc cria como new RegExp não precisa das '/' '/' da uma olhada no fiddle, mas como eu falei, precisa melhorar a regexp para atender exatamente a necessidade

Comment: Isso eu tambem esqueci que não necessitava, mas a regex fica esta que coloquei a cima.

Comment: Vai depender do que ele vai querer fazer, dessa forma vai pegar somente quando começar com a string certo?(não sou CRANIO em regex rs perdoe a ignorancia) eu fiz um teste sem pattern nem nada, só usando a string por exemplo com "a" somente ele vai pegar todas as palavras que tiver "a" em qualquer lugar, já com "buf" ele trouxe somente o bufalo. mas agradeço o complemento da resposta

Answer (score 0):

Tendo isto como base inicial, conclui com êxito tal feito, que pretendia. Agora, compartilho com vocês.

***Caixa de Sugestão - Lista Ordenada por Letra***, afim de ter uma idéia de como pode ser conseguido este efeito, posto o ***código completo*** como exemplo para estudo e/ou pesquisa por outros usuários.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Caixa de Sugestao - Lista Ordenada por Alfabeto</title>

<style>

  .campo
{
    color:#333;
    width:320px;
    height: 32px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: "tahoma";
    font-size: 11pt;
    text-vertical:top;
    padding:7px 5px 7px 5px;
    float:center;
}

.dicas
{ 
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>

<script>

<!--// Bloco 1 - rotina 2 em 1 - Validar Campo & Exibir/Fechar Div //-->

function validar(){
document.getElementById('1').style.display='block';
if(document.getElementById('txt').value.length < 1){  //Esta linha ira validar se uma tecla foi pressionada dentro do campo
document.getElementById('1').style.display= "block";
document.getElementById('txt').focus();
return false
}
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = "";
}

<!--// Bloco 2 - Listagem de Nomes - Ordenada por Letras do Alfabeto //-->

function lista(){
letras = ["Alex","Adrian","Adriano","Alexander","Alessandro","Ana","Aline","Ãgata","Alice","Amanda","Bryan","Breno","Bruno","Bernardo","Benjamin","Bruna","Belisa","Brenda","BÃ¡rbara","Beatriz","Caio","CauÃª","CauÃ£","Carlos","ClÃ©ber","Carol","Clara","Camila","Carolina","Clarissa","David","Diego","Diogo","Danilo","Daniel","Dalila","Diana","DÃ©bora","Daniela","Eduardo","Elvis","Emanuel","Edson","Enzo","Eliza","Ãrica","Estela","Eduarda","Elizabeth","Felipe","FÃ¡bio","Fabiano","Francisco","Fernando","FelÃ­cia","FabÃ­ola","Filipa","FlÃ¡via","Fabiana","Gabriel","Gustavo","Giovanni","Guilherme","GregÃ³rio","Gabriela","Giulia","Gisela","Graziela","Gabriele","Hugo","HÃ©lio","Heitor","HÃ©rcules","Henrique","Helena","HeloÃ­sa","Igor","InÃ¡cio","Ivan","Ian","Iago","Ãris","Iara","Isa","Isadora","Isabel","Joaquim","Jonathan","JosÃ©","jonas","joÃ£o","JÃ©ssica","Joyce","JÃºlia","Juliana","Kevin","Kaio","Kelvin","Karina","kethlen","karen","kelly","Lucas","Leandro","Luciano","LÃºcio","LÃ­via","Lis","Lilian","LetÃ­cia","Larissa","Matheus","Marcos","Miguel","Michel","Manuel","Marina","Mariana","Melissa","MarÃ­lia","Micaela","Natanael","Nicolas","Natan","Nataniel","Nilton","Nara","Nina","NÃºbia","Natacha","Oliver","OtÃ¡vio","Orlando","OlÃ­via","Pedro","Paulo","Pablo","Paula","Pietra","Priscila","Paloma","PatrÃ­cia","Rafael","Ricardo","Rodrigo","RÃ´mulo","Ronaldo","Reinaldo","Rafaela","RÃºbia","Raquel","Rita","Rebeca","Samuel","SÃ©rgio","Santiago","Sabrina","Serena","Sara","Sofia","Samara","Tiago","TomÃ¡s","TÃºlio","Theo","Thiago","Tabita","Tamara","TaÃ­s","Tamires","Talita","Ulisses","Umberto","Ueber","Victor","VinicÃ­us","Vagner","Violeta","VitÃ³ria","Valesca","Vanessa","ValquÃ­ria","Wanessa","Walter","Wilton","Yudi","Yuri","Yago","Yan","Yara","Yohana","Yasmin","Zoe"];
letras.sort();
alfabeto = letras.filter(function(el){
campo = document.getElementById('txt').value;
regex = new RegExp('^'+campo+'.*','i');
return el.match(regex);
});

<!--// Percorrendo os elementos do Array, apos digitar a letra desejada //-->
<!--// Sera montada a tabela dinamica com os resultados dentro da Div //-->

for (var i in alfabeto){ 
    tabela = document.getElementById('1');
tabela.innerHTML += "<table width='100%'><tr><td>"+ alfabeto[i] +"</td></tr></table>";
}
}

<!--// Bloco 3 - Selecionar Linha da Tabela - Dando Cor ao Fundo da Linha ao Passar o Mouse //-->

window.onmouseover=function(){
td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(i in td){
td[i].onmouseover=function(){ preto =this.style.backgroundColor='#999999'; document.getElementsByTagName('td') = preto }
td[i].onmouseout=function(){ branco =this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'; document.getElementsByTagName('td') = branco  }
td[i].onclick=function(){ valor = this.innerHTML; document.getElementById('txt').value = valor; alert( "Oi " + valor + ", tudo bem!");}
}
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Indice de Nomes</h2>

<h3>Lista de Nomes de A a Z</h3>

<h4>Digite uma letra abaixo:</h4>
<center>

<input onkeypress="validar()" class="campo" id="txt" value="" onkeyup="lista()" type="text">

<div id="1" class="dicas" style="display: none;" onclick="this.style.display='none';"></div>

</center>

</body>

</html>
```

**w3schools** - [Veja uma amostra](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEMHBW821DCQ)